# Empty addresses in order when using Paypal Express

Tags: paypal-express, enterprise-1.14

We try to enable the Paypal Express Checkout in EE v1.14.1.0.

However, the **shipping and billing addresses are empty** when we return from Paypal.
Because of this, we also run into the error on the `paypal/express/review/` page that the order can't be created because we need to select a shipping method.

I checked the `payment_paypal_express.log` file for the response sent back to Magento from Paypal, the address data is actually filled in this response, but somehow lost when trying to create the actual order in Magento:

```
...
        [FIRSTNAME] => Test
        [LASTNAME] => User
        [COUNTRYCODE] => GB
        [SHIPTONAME] => Test User
        [SHIPTOSTREET] => 1 Main Terrace
        [SHIPTOCITY] => Wolverhampton
        [SHIPTOSTATE] => West Midlands
        [SHIPTOZIP] => W12 4LQ
        [SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE] => GB
        [SHIPTOCOUNTRYNAME] => United Kingdom
        [ADDRESSSTATUS] => Confirmed
...
```

We run the Express checkout in sandbox mode, so the payment is verified and all.

What can be the cause of this?

Comment: Have you opened a ticket with Magento on the issue?

Answer (score 1):

your symptoms are slightly different, but please consider the response we received from Paypal, https://stackoverflow.com/a/30905055/336905